# Entity Framework 6 raw sql query returns 0 in place of int value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I have a small problem where one of my queries return proper integer values in SQL Server 2008 yet when I run the query through `ctx.Database.SqlQuery<>` it makes all integer column values as 0.

Other columns such as `DateTime` or `varchar` return proper data.

Sample query result in SQL Server 2008:

```
2015-03-08  F4U4    H012    Line 01 0   15916   147 190 15390   0   0   0
```

Same query result in EF using the following code:

```
using (MEYNDBEntities ctx = new MEYNDBEntities())
{
    var obj = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<DBResultDPRDataUpload>(query).ToList();
    return obj;
}

2015-03-08  F4U4    H012    Line 01 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I am able to query the same database context with other queries using the same procedure and it returns integer values without any issue.

What can be the issue here? Please let me know if more information is required.

Sample select statement:

```
SELECT 
   convert(DATE, getdate()) AS DPRDate
   ,substring(label, 0, charindex('-', label)) AS Farm
   ,substring(label, charindex('-', label) + 1, len(label)) AS House
   ,'Line 01' AS [LineNo]
   ,0 AS [Live BC]
   ,d.TBC AS [Net BC]
   ,b.noDoas AS [Number of DOAs]
   ,c.ROA AS [Number of ROAs]
   ,d.TBW AS [DBW]
   ,0 AS [LBW]
   ,0 AS [DOA Weight]
   ,0 AS [ROA Weight]
FROM 
   <multiple tables>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

0 indicates that you want to get integer value but you are getting nothing from stored procedure check the values and run the stored procedure in sqlserver with default values .